# Как сделать ссылку на полную статью?

Tags: mysql, php, get

Вот смотрите, я вывел цикл из базы данных, теперь мне надо сделать ссылку на полную статью. Я сделал дополнительную страницу для полной новости, назвал news.php, и на название приклеил ссылку, вот сам код блока:

```
<?php
$result=mysqlquery("SELECT name,image,classfilt,heightimg FROM mackmybase");
$n=mysql_num_rows($result);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo <<< HEREDOC
<a href="/news.php">
<ul id="tiles">
<li class="$row[classfilt]"><img src="$row[image]" height="$row[heightimg]" width="200">
<p>$row[name]</p>
</li>      
</ul>
</a>
HEREDOC;
};

function mysqlquery($query){ // для удобной отладки
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die("Неверный запрос: ".mysql_error()."\n".$query);
    return $result;
};
?>
```

В ссылке надо что-то сделать? Подскажите.

Comment: код отформатируйте.

Answer (score 3):

Может быть доставать из БД еще и id новости и передавать его в скрипт news.php

```
<a href="/news.php?id=$row['id']">
```

А в скрипте news.php брать этот id и доставать полный текст новости.

Comment: Да-да, именно так и надо. в news.php должно быть $_GET['id']